# How to create a gem repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, capistrano, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy my local app to dreamhost using Capistrano. While running the `cap deploy:cold` for the first time, I'm getting an error for missing gems. The dreamhost wiki also recommends that users should maintain their own gem repository in the folder `$HOME/.gems` .

Going back to the main question :

1. Where are the .gem files stored locally? I can find the individual gem folders in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/` (on my mac). But I cannot find the respective `.gem` files.
2. Would copying these `.gem` files to the server at the location `$HOME/.gems/gems` solve the problem of missing gems?
3. Is there a better way to avoid this?

Comment: In production , bundler creates a dedicated gem rep in the folder of your deployed app.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put your gems in a folder and point your app to that; however, this is obsolete. Bundler what what you should use. Below is an article on how it works with DH:

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Bundler#Get_Your_App_Using_Bundler

Comment: I am not able to run any "bundle" commands on my dreamhost terminal. [etamin]$ bundle show
-bash: bundle: command not found